# draft js editor scrolling issue with new line

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

The issue is when I press enter, it starts typing on a new line that is initially hidden. However, once I type 2 characters, it suddenly jumps down, making the text visible again.

Here is my lib details:

```
"draft-js": "^0.11.7",
"react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

After many struggles, I finally found a solution with CSS by overriding the '`DraftEditor-editorContainer`' class.

```
.DraftEditor-editorContainer {
  height: 200px; // my text editor height
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0px 14px;
}
```

you can see the result here.

[image]